# Adding dll created in VC++ in C# 2010

Tags: c#

I have a dll created in VC++ and visual studio 2005 now i want to add same dll in my C# application and VS2010.

But whenever i tried it gives me erro 
"a reference to "../name.dll"could not be added please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or com component"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like C++ dll is [native dll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3995607/649524) (and not managed [C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163852.aspx))

You need to look at P/Invoke.

[Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx)
[DLL Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx)

Comment: P/Invoke has a steep learning curve. It requires time to grasp what is going inside. Update the question with more details.